# How to rebuild chromium to change object default configurable property

Tags: javascript, c++, ecmascript-6, chromium

I am looking for a way to add additional logic when a javascript script makes call to `window.location`, e.g add logic when calling getter of `window.location`  through a Proxy or redefine with Object.defineProperties.
When checking default js code as in `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window,'location')` we got the property `{configurable: false}`. Are there any way theoretically, by modifying the source code of a javacript engine and its C++ object implementation ( like Chrome v8 engine with the comment idea in  data_object_builder.h
: "Constructs a JavaScript object with a series of data properties. (As with default data properties in JavaScript, these properties are
configurable, writable and enumerable.)"

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/b698c15c43d9d7db4d1aa99119af5d0a34af4249/gin/data_object_builder.h#L18),
to make the location object configurable (true) in my own browser build?

Comment: You should ask this question to Chromium developers by raising an issue in their repo.

Comment: I did not see a response there so I am looking for extra ideas and suggestions, thank you